# Сортировка найденного товара

Tags: javascript, битрикс, 1с

Есть сайт, у которого есть поиск по каталогу(например, вывод товара по слову в названии), нужно этот товар отсортировать по цене (например, нажав на кнопку "сначала дорогие" будет выводиться товар с дорогого и самый последний будет самый дешевый).

Переменная стоимости товара, в ней хранится цена товара:

```
$item['CATALOG_PRICE_1']








                <? if ($arCurSection['DEPTH_LEVEL'] != 1) : ?>
                    <div class="wrap-sort">
                        <form action="#" method="post">
                            <div class="sort">
                                <b>Сортировать по:</b>
                                <ul>
                                    <? $urlWithParams = $APPLICATION->GetCurPage(); ?>
                                    <? if (!( empty($_GET["by"]) ) && !( empty($_GET["order"]) ) && ( $_GET["by"] != "show_counter" )): ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="<?= $urlWithParams; ?>?by=show_counter&order=desc<?= $szParam; ?>">популярности</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <? if ($_GET["order"] == "asc"): ?>
                                            <li class="active">
                                                <span>сначала недорогие</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?= $urlWithParams; ?>?by=price&order=desc<?= $szParam; ?>">сначала дорогие</a>
                                            </li>
                                        <? else: ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?= $urlWithParams; ?>?by=price&order=asc<?= $szParam; ?>">сначала недорогие</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="active">
                                                <span>сначала дорогие</span>
                                            </li>
                                        <? endif; ?>
                                    <? else: ?>
                                        <li class="active">
                                            <span>популярности</span>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="<?= $urlWithParams; ?>?by=price&order=asc<?= $szParam; ?>">сначала недорогие</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="<?= $urlWithParams; ?>?by=price&order=desc<?= $szParam; ?>">сначала дорогие</a>
                                        </li>
                                    <? endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

этот сортировщик применяется к другой странице, можно ли его научить сортировать товар, который был получен из формы поиска ?

Comment: Где вы хотите сортировать ? На клиенте ? Сервере ? Покажите код. Сейчас вопрос закроют т.к. он "слишком общий"

Comment: сортировать желательно на клиенте, какой код вам показать ? предоставлю все что нужно, кнопок сортировки пока нет, есть шаблон RAND вывода товара

Comment: покажите тогда ваши обьекты в json формате.

Comment: вообще, по факту, есть уже один сортировщик, но он сортирует другую страницу

Comment: как метка [tag:java] относится к вопросу?

Comment: @АлексейСергеевич ну так примените его к Вашей задае. Если не получится, то задавайте вопрос

Comment: он сортирует благодаря ?by=price&order=desc в ссылке, добавив этот кусок в страницу с поиском никакой сортировки не происходит.

Comment: Не имеет смысла проводить сортировку товаров на клиенте, особенно учитывая то, что вы получаете параметры с указанием сортировки на сервер. Приведите, пожалуйста, код выборки результатов поиска. Подозреваю, что у вас 1С-Битрикс, и поможет вот это: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic43895/